# Unable to call dictionary dataclass attribute with cls in function but can if I use class name

Tags: python, oop, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to run the below code and getting some strange errors... Wondering if anyone can help!

```
import feedparser
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict


@dataclass
class NewsParser:
    shipping_news: str = "shippingurlgoeshere"
    all_shipping_news: Dict = field(default_factory=lambda: {
        'shipping news': "shippingurlgoeshere"
    })

    @classmethod
    def parse_feed(cls):
        """
        Parses a news feed for relevant information.
        :return: relevant_items_as_dictionary, dictionary (unsurprisingly) which contains lists of the relevant items.
        """

        # Get articles from feed

        content = feedparser.parse(cls.all_shipping_news["shipping news"])
        articles = content.entries

        # Parse feed

        titles = [x.title for x in articles]
        urls = [x.link for x in articles]
        pub_date_string = [x.published for x in articles]
        pub_date_tuple = [x.published_parsed for x in articles]
        html_summaries = [x.summary for x in articles]

        relevant_items_as_dictionary = {"titles": titles, "urls": urls, "pub_date_string": pub_date_string,
                                        "pub_date_tuple": pub_date_tuple, "html_summaries": html_summaries}

        return relevant_items_as_dictionary


NewsParser.parse_feed()
```

This gives me the error AttributeError: type object 'NewsParser' has no attribute 'all_shipping_news'

But if I comment out `NewsParser.parse_feed()` and just print `NewsParser` after instantiating it, I get the correct result:

NewsParser(shipping_news='shippingurlgoeshere', all_shipping_news={'shipping news': 'shippingurlgoeshere'})

But if instead of writing `cls.all_shipping_news` I write `NewsParser.all_shipping_news` it works fine.

Last piece of the puzzle... If in the parse_feed method I write `cls.shipping_news` then it can access the shipping_news string perfectly, but as above this doesn't happen when I write `cls.all_shipping_news`

Comment: why `NewsParser = NewsParser()` if you are using a classmethod? no need to create an instance.

Comment: Yeah you're right no need, I just left that in from when I was testing to see if I can attribute the class attributes OK after creating an instance. Will take out in case it's confusing!

Comment: Because the class **doesn't have that attribute**. It's an instance attribute

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga ! Is there a way for me to amend the code so that it does have that attribute?

Comment: Remove `@classmethod` and call `NewParser().parse_feed()`